# facebook Open Graph Object Debugger gives error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I get the error:
`Object at URL 'http://quaaoutlodge.com/content/fashion-show' of type 'website' is invalid because the given value 'QuaaoutLodge' for property 'fb:app_id' could not be parsed as type 'fbid'.` from [Open Graph Object Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) while the meta tags in my html look like:

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="QuaaoutLodge" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="Ron Eggler" />
```

What's the problem here?

Comment: meta property fb:app_id should be an integer and it should be a facebook app id : for more detail https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/object-type/website/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment above, your OG meta tags are incorrect. You should specifying them as follows:

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="1234" />
<meta property="fb:admins" content="5678" />
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="123456789" />
```

Assuming '123456789' is your Facebook app ID (which you look up here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) and '1234' and '5678' are valid user ID's.

** for the "fb:admins" tags, note that you should be specifying one for each admin.